# Having trouble with node.js client joining a XMPP Prosody room

Tags: xmpp, node-xmpp, prosody-im

I have installed XMPP prosody server on my ubuntu VM. After installation, in the config file of prosody server. I left the VirtualHost part untouched(i.e it points to localhost). Then in the components part I uncommented and changed Conference.example.com to Conference.localhost. These are the only changes I did in the config file.

**Scenario 1**->I tried creating a room using pidgin client. This part was successful. Then I made my node.js @xmpp/client join this room by sending its presence to the room. This was also successful. Then I was able to send messages between the two clients. So, everything worked in scenario 1.

**Scenario 2** ->I tried creating the room using node.js @xmpp/client. This part was successful. Then I made another node.js client join the same room by sending its presence to the room. This part fails for me. The error I get can be seen below.

*OUT
{presence from="sameer@localhost/3dh65FV7" to="watchparty@conference.localhost/sameer">}*

*IN
{presence to="sameer@localhost/3dh65FV7" from="watchparty@conference.localhost/sameer" type="error">}*

**Client1.js**(client that creates the room)

```
const { client, xml } = require("@xmpp/client");
const debug = require("@xmpp/debug");

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
let fromAddr;

const xmpp = client({
  service: "xmpp://192.168.0.59:5222",
  domain: "localhost",
  username: "venki",
  password: "Welcome1",
});

debug(xmpp, true);

xmpp.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

xmpp.on("offline", () => {
  console.log("offline");
});

xmpp.on("stanza", async (stanza) => {
  if (stanza.is("message")) {
    // await xmpp.send(xml("presence", { type: "unavailable" }));
    // await xmpp.stop();
  }
});

async function sendMessageToRoomWatchParty() {
  const message = xml('message', {from: fromAddr, to: 'watchparty@conference.localhost', type: 'groupchat'},
  xml('body',{},'Hello from Venki'));
  await xmpp.send(message);
}

async function joinRoomWatchParty() {
  const roomAddr = 'watchparty@conference.localhost/venki';
  const presence = xml('presence', {from: fromAddr, to: roomAddr},
   xml('x', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'}));
   await xmpp.send(presence);

  setTimeout(sendMessageToRoomWatchParty,10000); 
}

xmpp.on("online", async (address) => {
  fromAddr = address;
  setTimeout(joinRoomWatchParty,5000);
});

xmpp.start().catch(console.error);
```

**Client2.js**(client that joins the room)

```
const { client, xml } = require("@xmpp/client");
const debug = require("@xmpp/debug");

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
let fromAddr;

const xmpp = client({
  service: "xmpp://192.168.1.19:5222",
  domain: "localhost",
  username: "sameer",
  password: "Welcome1",
});

debug(xmpp, true);

xmpp.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

xmpp.on("offline", () => {
  console.log("offline");
});

xmpp.on("stanza", async (stanza) => {
  if (stanza.is("message")) {
    // await xmpp.send(xml("presence", { type: "unavailable" }));
    // await xmpp.stop();
  }
});

async function joinRoomWatchParty() {
  const roomAddr = 'watchparty@conference.localhost/sameer';
  const presence = xml('presence', {from: fromAddr, to: roomAddr},
   xml('x', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'})
   );
   await xmpp.send(presence);
}

xmpp.on("online", async (address) => {
  fromAddr = address;
  setTimeout(joinRoomWatchParty,5000);
});

xmpp.start().catch(console.error);
```

**Why is scenario 2 failing?** I sense there is some mistake I'm doing with creation of the room using node.js client. Please go through my client1.js code.

Please help.

Comment: I was able to find the reason why scenario 2 was failing.

It seems the room will be locked by default even after its created. So the owner has to unlock the room after creating the room. Refer to the below link for how to properly create and unlock the room.
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom